# How to run a large data.frame using LMER?

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, large-data, lme4

I am working with a large data.frame that contains around 1.4 million observations. Initially when i was running my models, i was working on a sub-sample (10% of my full-sample). This is because running one model can take around two hours with the original data. Once i was sure that all variables are well harmonized and all regressions were running fine, i ran my models using the full sample. However, the regression did not converge and i received the following two errors from two different models:

```
Error in fun(xaa, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite

Error in fun(xss, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite
```

I am not sure if this is relevant but my laptop specifications are:
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

**Processor**: 2.5 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7

**Memory**: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

**Graphics**: Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

The data is hierarchical and structured as the following: individuals (level 1) -> country_year (level 2) -> country (level 3).

I use the `lmer` function to fit this model together and i include a random slope at the 2nd and 3rd level. Below you find a reproducible code. Could someone please guide me on how to get around this issue?

```
df <- tibble(
  y = rnorm(1400000),
  x1 = rnorm(1400000),
  x2 = rnorm(1400000),
  country =sample.int(30,size=1400000,replace=TRUE)-1,
  country_year =sample.int(10,size=1400000,replace=TRUE)-1
  )

df$country = as.factor(df$country)
df$country_year = as.factor(df$country_year)

library(lme4)
model1 <- lmer(y~ x1 + x2 +  
              (x1 + x2 |country_year) +
              (x1 + x2 |country), data=df)
```